# Finding standard Matrix for a linear transformation

Tags: linear-transformations

[image: Finding Standard Matrix]

I'm supposed to determine if there is enough information to find the standard matrix and find it if able to. 
The answer that is given in the book is that there is enough information but it doesn't provide me with the steps. Hope to get some help on how to get started on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The standard matrix, $A$ of a linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$, is such that

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}T(\vec{e_1}) & T(\vec{e_2}) & T(\vec{e_3})
\end{bmatrix}$$

Next, observe that

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix} & = \vec{e_1}+ \vec{e_2}+ \vec{e_3} \\
T(\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}) & = T(\vec{e_1})+ T(\vec{e_2})+ T(\vec{e_3})=\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 3 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Similarly,

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix} & = 2\vec{e_1}+ \vec{e_2}+ 3\vec{e_3} \\
T(\begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1 \\ 3
\end{bmatrix}) & = 2T(\vec{e_1})+ T(\vec{e_2})+ 3T(\vec{e_3})=\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

and,

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix} & = -\vec{e_1}+ \vec{e_2}+ 2\vec{e_3} \\
T(\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 2
\end{bmatrix}) & = -T(\vec{e_1})+ T(\vec{e_2})+ 2T(\vec{e_3})=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Can you do the rest?